# How does the drug MBC effect the depolymerization of microtubules in eukaryotic cells?

Tags: cell-biology

I have tried to look for the mechanism of how methyl benzimidazol-2-yl-carbamate affects microtubules in eukaryotes, but what I found wasn't very useful:

1. Quilan et al 1980 assert that it acts by inhibiting polymerization of microtubules rather than by directly depolymerizing them.
2. In "The Cytoskeleton: A Target for Toxic Agents", it is mentioned that

> ..strains of Aspergillus that were resistant to the drug had a lower affinity for MBC in a binding assay, whereas super-sensitive strains had a higher affinity for the drug.

Any references would be appreciated.

**In Summary:** I would like to know how the drug MBC effects the depolymerization of microtubules in eukaryotic cells. I would also appreciate any scientific references.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange! I made a few edits to your post, you are welcomed to change it back to the original if you feel it better describes your question.

Answer (score 1):

Carbendazim inhibits microtubule polymerization by directly binding to tubulin, preventing subunits from interacting. Therefore, mytotic spindle malforms and potentially causes aneuploidy in affected cells. Mechanisms of resistance are often [shown to be changes in membrane permeability](http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs-wm/25082.pdf) to the compound.

---

[CARBENDAZIM (addendum)](http://www.inchem.org/documents/jmpr/jmpmono/v2005pr05.pdf)